# Triviality of Sp(TM)

Tags: differential-topology, symplectic-geometry, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles

Let M be a symplectic manifold of dimension $2n$ and $TM$ denote its tangent bundle. Let Sp(TM) denote the bundle over M whose fibers are linear maps preserving symplectic structure on M. Is Sp(TM) trivial (i.e can it be written as $M \times Sp(2n)$) because Id gives a cross section and existence of a global cross section imply the fiber bundle is trivial?

Edit: I will include more context. I want to understand the paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1305.6810.pdf , what I am asking is defined at page 5 around the middle of the page starting with Letting Sp(TM).. Now I am thinking it is perhaps not a principal G bundle it is maybe rather just a fiber bundle with a fiber equal to Lie Group and since there is no equivariant G action, I cannot use the existence of Id section to trivialize the bundle. The concepts are rather new to me, so it would be great if someone can present their perspective.

Comment: $Sp(TM)$ is a principal $Sp(2n)$-bundle so $Sp(2n)$ acts simply transitively on the fibers, but the fibers aren't canonically identified with $Sp(2n)$ so it doesn't make sense to say which element corresponds to the identity. If $Sp(TM)$ admits a section, then the corresponding point in each fiber gives a choice of identity.

Comment: Fibers are not canonically identified with Sp(2n) however at each point $m\in M$ $id_{T_pM}$ exist independent of basis/trivialization choice.

Comment: I see. I thought $Sp(TM)$ was the symplectic frame bundle (for which my comments stand), but you're describing a different bundle.

Comment: I also would have thought $\operatorname{Sp}(TM)$ stands for the symplectic frame bundle (which as Michael says, is not trivial in general). From the tags on your question, you seem to indicate that $\operatorname{Sp}(TM)$ is a principal bundle. If so, how does $\operatorname{Sp}(2n,\mathbb{R})$ act on it, i.e. if $L\in\operatorname{Sp}(TM)_p$ (so $L:T_pM\to T_pM$), and $g\in\operatorname{Sp}(2n,\mathbb{R})$, what is $L\cdot g$?

Comment: I have edited the question to include context where I see this and my understanding. @user17945 just because the fibers are Lie group of symplectomorphisms, I think I just took it for granted that there is a right multiplication action, but now after you explicitly ask I realize that Sp(2n) does not canonically act on these fibers. So the question in some sense is not well posed hence I added the paper to put it in a context.

Comment: Just to be clear, given a symplectic manifold $(M,\omega)$, the fiber of $Sp(TM)$ above $p\in M$ is given by $\{f:T_pM\rightarrow T_p M:  f$ is linear and $f^\ast (\omega_p) = \omega_p\}$, right?

Comment: @JasonDeVito Yes, that is right.

Comment: @Lucky, I believe your amended assessment is correct - $\operatorname{Sp}(TM)$ is not a principal bundle, and so the existence of a global section does not guarantee it is trivial.

Comment: Then it's not clear to me whether or not the bundle is principal.  Locally, it's easy to define the action of $Sp(2n,\mathbb{R})$: using Darboux coordinates, we can locally write $\omega = \sum d p^i \wedge dq^i$.  Then $Sp(2n,\mathbb{R})$ acts on $Sp(TM)_p$ by composition.  But I haven't been able to work out whether these patch together nicely.

Comment: @JasonDeVito I think it is plausible that it is not principal. Here is why I thought that, similar to this construction given any vector bundle over a manifold M we can define the bundle on M whose fibers are Lie group of linear automorphisms of fibers (nothing symplectic) then Id again is a cross section of this bundle and if this were to be a principal fiber bundle, we could have argued that bundle would be trivial. This looks like too much without any condition on the vector bundle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding this in response to Jason DeVito's comment: $\operatorname{Sp}(TM)$ as defined is not a principal fibre bundle. In fact, it is an associated bundle to the symplectic frame bundle (which *is* principal).

To see this: let me use the notation $\mathcal{F}_{\operatorname{Sp}}(M)$ for the symplectic frame bundle of $M$. One way of defining $\mathcal{F}_{\operatorname{Sp}}(M)$ is that its fibre $\mathcal{F}_{\operatorname{Sp}}(M)_p$ over $p\in M$ consists of all symplectic linear isomorphisms from $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ with its standard symplectic form $\Omega$ to $(T_pM,\omega_p)$

$$
\mathcal{F}_{\operatorname{Sp}}(M)_p = \{ b_p:\mathbb{R}^{2n}\to T_pM \mid b_p^*\omega_p = \Omega\}
$$

(see for example [Metaplectic-c Quantomorphisms](https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.5529) by Jennifer Vaughan, Section 3.2, where the symplectic frame bundle is denoted $\operatorname{Sp}(M,\omega)$). This is a principal $\operatorname{Sp}(2n,\mathbb{R})$-bundle, with action given by composition

$$
(b_p, T)\in \mathcal{F}_{\operatorname{Sp}}(M) \times \operatorname{Sp}(2n,\mathbb{R}) \mapsto b_p\circ T \in \mathcal{F}_{\operatorname{Sp}}(M).
$$

I claim that (your) $\operatorname{Sp}(TM)$ is isomorphic to the associated bundle
$$
\mathcal{F}_{\operatorname{Sp}}(M)\times_{\operatorname{Sp}(2n,\mathbb{R})} \operatorname{Sp}(2n,\mathbb{R})
$$
where the action of $\operatorname{Sp}(2n,\mathbb{R})$ on itself is via conjugation. That is, for $b_p\in \mathcal{F}_{\operatorname{Sp}}(M), S\in\operatorname{Sp}(2n,\mathbb{R})$, the associated bundle is the quotient under the equivalence relation
$$
(b_p, S) \sim (b_p\circ T, T^{-1}\circ S \circ T)
$$
with $T\in \operatorname{Sp}(2n,\mathbb{R})$. The isomorphism between this associated bundle and $\operatorname{Sp}(TM)$ is given by
$$
[b_p,S] \mapsto b_p\circ S\circ b_p^{-1}
$$
where $[b_p,S]$ denotes the equivalence class of $(b_p,S)$. It is not too difficult to check that this is well-defined, and a bijection.

This hopefully clarifies that $\operatorname{Sp}(TM)$ is not a principal bundle, but rather an associated fibre bundle.

Comment: This does show that it is an associated fibre bundle however I want to make sure I understand so I will ask: strictly speaking this does not prove that this fiber bundle (Sp(TM) does not admit some Sp(2n) principal bundle structure, right?

Comment: There would certainly be cases where it could admit a principal $\operatorname{Sp}(2n,\mathbb{R})$ structure. For example, suppose $\mathcal{F}_{\operatorname{Sp}}(M)$ were trivial, i.e. isomorphic to $M\times\operatorname{Sp}(2n,\mathbb{R})$. Then we would have $\operatorname{Sp}(TM) \simeq M\times \operatorname{Sp}(2n,\mathbb{R})$, and this has an obvious right $\operatorname{Sp}(2n,\mathbb{R})$-action. But this is not canonical (since the trivialisation of $\mathcal{F}_{\operatorname{Sp}}(M)$ is not canonical). I think the point is there's no obvious general construction.

Comment: I agree that this answer shows that it's unlikely that  $Sp(TM)$ will be a principal bundle in general.  Still, it would be nice to see an explicit counterexample.  I'll think about this for a bit and see if I can come up with one on my own.  Thanks!